# How to select the last value which is not null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
id a b 
1  1 kate
1  4 null
1  3 paul
1  3 paul
1  2 lola
2  1 kim
2  9 null
2  2 null
```

In result it should be this:

```
1 3 paul
2 1 kim
```

I want to get the last `a` where `b is not null`. Something like:

```
select b
from (select,b 
row_num() over (partition by id order by a desc) as num) as f
where num = 1
```

But this way I get a null value, because to the last `a = 4` corresponds to `b IS NULL`. Maybe there is a way to rewrite `ffill` method from pandas?

Comment: I assume the desired result should read `kim` instead of `kate`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- `a` is defined `NOT NULL`.
- You want the row with the greatest `a` where `b IS NOT NULL` - ***per `id`***.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  b IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY id, a DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc6260bcc3759f7d5682d040599052a7)*

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select id, a, b
from (select id, a, b,
    row_num() over (partition by id order by a desc nulls last) as num
    from unnamedTable) t
where num = 1
```

Or, if that isn't right, try it with `nulls first`. I can never remember which way it works with `desc`.

Comment: I had the same thought. Unfortunately the nulls are in column b.

Comment: Oh, you're right. In that case, use shawnt00's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622920/696808).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't guaranteed to have at least one non-null per `id` then you'll want to move nulls to the bottom of the list rather than filtering those rows out entirely.

```
select id, a, b
from (
    select id, a, b, 
        row_number() over (
            partition by id
            order by case when b is not null then 0 else 1 end, a desc
        ) as num
) as f
where num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this around a `cte` and `join` it back to the main table if you wish to keep the original columns as is, but looking at your expected output and logic, this should do it. Having said that, `row_number()` based approach might be a tad faster.

```
select distinct 
       id, 
       max(a) over (partition by id) as a, 
       first_value(b) over (partition by id order by a desc) as b
from tbl
where b is not null;
```